# Validate that an unprivileged user has the correct access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I created a simple unprivileged user on my Ubuntu system which will be used to run my network applications (Firefox, etc..) from a limited user.

My purpose is to lower the possible damage that can be caused to my data in case of a malicious site trying to exploit a vulnerability in one of these network applications.

Is there a simple way to check that this limited user really limited as I expect it to be?

For example, I ran **`find / -perm -o=w`** to see if there are important files that this user has permission to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic bullet. You could hire a professional to do a security audit, and even then you wouldn't be completely sure.

Your best bet is to log in as this user (or execute commands under `su limiteduser`), and try poking where you shouldn't. For example `su limiteduser -c 'find / -writable'` will report all the files the user can write to.